# Double integral problem: Substitution where the region is defined as inequalities.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am having trouble with the following problem:

Find the area of the region $R=\{(x,y)|x\leq0 , e^{x} \leq y \leq e^{\frac{1}{2} x} \}$, by means of the substitution $x=\ln(u^2 v) $, $ y=uv$ for $u,v>0$.

We have from lectures that $area(R) = \iint_R1dx dy $ and I have worked out that the Jacobian is equal to 1 (well, unless I've done that wrong. . .). But I am struggling with how to transform the region R using this substitution. Just plugging the x and y into the boundaries for R gives $\ln(u^2 v) \leq 0$ and $ u^2 v \leq uv \leq \sqrt{u^2 v} $, is doing this then manipulating the inequalities to get ones for u and v the right approach? (As I can't seem to find anything useful when trying this).

Hints would be preferable to answers as this is for homework, but any help would be appreciated.

Oh, and that counts for links to similar questions I've just just not found.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints only. (note that  $\log (u^2v)\leq 0$ is equivalent to $u^2v\leq 1$). Now look at your inequality $uv\leq \sqrt{u^2v}$. Simplify by $u>0$. What condition have you obtained on $v$ ?

Comment: So, 
$$uv \leq \sqrt{u^2 v} =u \sqrt{v} \iff v \leq \sqrt{v}$$
Dividing by $u$ is valid since $u \gt 0$.
From this we can deduce that 
$$v \leq 1$$
Along the right lines? Would you rearrange $u^2v \leq 1$ to get a condition for $u$, and use the original fact that $u,v \gt 0$ too?

Comment: Ok for $v\leq 1$. Now use $u^2v\leq uv$ to show that $u\leq 1$. If $D_1$ is your original domain (in $u$, $v$) and $D_2=\{(u,v),0<u\leq 1, 0<v\leq 1\}$, you have shown that $D_1\subset D_2$. I think it is easy to finish.

Comment: Right, yes I have that now. To be honest I expect the whole question was intended to be easy to finish, I'm just bad at substitutions with multiple integrals. . .

Thanks for your help :)